# The correct way to override an initializer in Swift 1.1

Tags: swift, initialization

This used to work in Xcode 6.1 beta:

```
class MainViewController: NSViewController {
  convenience override init() {
    self.init(nibName: "MainView", bundle: nil)
  }
}
```

After I switch to 6.1 GM2, it doesn't compile. Looks like the issue is related to "[failable initializers](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH34-XID_683)" introduced in Swift 1.1. I've tried `convenience override init?()`, `convenience init?()` and `override init?()`, neither worked.

So what's the correct way to override this kind of initializers as of today?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're trying to implement `init()` — a non-failable initializer — by delegating to `init?(nibName:bundle:)`, which is a failable initializer. This doesn't work: if the `super.init` call fails, you'd be left with a non-initialized instance, which Swift won't allow.

Or to put it another way, the result of using a failable initializer is an optional, and you can't use an optional in place of a non-optional value. And in the case of class initialization and inheritance, you can't substitute a non-optional `self` for an optional one — you can only delegate the setup of `self`'s state to a different initializer.

Instead, you can remove optionality/failability with a little song and dance:

```
class MainViewController: NSViewController {
    override init!(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
        // check state here and provide app-specific diagnostic if it's wrong
    }
    convenience override init() {
        self.init(nibName: "MainView", bundle: nil)
    }

    // need this, too, or the compiler will complain that it's missing
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("not implemented") // ...or an actual implementation
    }
}
```

An `init!` initializer produces an implicitly unwrapped optional (IUO) — just as an IUO type can be used to bridge between code that works with optional and non-optional values, an `init!` initializer can bridge between failable and non-failable initializers. You can't delegate from a non-failable initializer to a failable initializer, but you can delegate from a non-failable initializer to an `init!` initializer and from an `init!` initializer to a failable initializer.

Here, the `NSViewController` initializer you want to use is fully failable, so you override it with an `init!` initializer. Then, you can declare a non-failable `convenience init` that delegates to your new `init!` initializer.

---

We often tend to avoid IUOs, and by extension `init!` initializers, because we generally want to either explicitly allow for (and require handling) failure or explicitly disallow it. However, one of the strongest general use cases for IUOs and their kin is to turn conditions that are guaranteed only outside of your source code into assertions that your code can treat as infallible. `IBOutlet`s are a great example of this — in your nib/storyboard you guarantee the state of your `IBOutlet` variables, but the compiler doesn't know about that — as are just about anything else to do with bundle resources.

This little delegation dance puts the burden of failure at a specific, easily debuggable place in your code — if the call from `init()` to `super.init(nibName:bundle:)` fails, your app will crash. But you can expect that call to fail only in very specific (and mostly at-development-time) conditions.

Comment: madness. how about some brevity, please apple.

Comment: This gives an error with Swift 1.2: "Initializer does not override a designated initializer from its superclass" ... i.e. the override  on 2. init has to be removed. Even with that, after compile third initializer throws its fatal error. How does that need to be implemented?

Comment: It's too complex.