# In Swift, why do I need to override this initialiser in order to make my own convenience initialiser?

Tags: ios, swift, initialization, overriding, uistoryboard

I have this class:

```
class MyStoryboard: UIStoryboard {
   override init() {
        super.init(name: "SomeName", bundle: nil);
    }
}
```

Swift does not accept this as I am not calling a designated initializer. But the header for UIStoryBoard has

```
@availability(iOS, introduced=5.0)
class UIStoryboard : NSObject {
    init(name: String, bundle storyboardBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) -> UIStoryboard

    func instantiateInitialViewController() -> AnyObject
    func instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(identifier: String) -> AnyObject!
}
```

There is no `convenience` keyword here. But say that it is a convenience initializer. Then this should work:

```
class CharacterStoryboard: UIStoryboard {        
    convenience override init() {
        self.init(name: "SomeName", bundle: nil);
    }
}
```

But this gives the error "Extra argument 'name' in call", as if this initializer doesn't even exist.

The only work around I have found is to do this:

```
class CharacterStoryboard: UIStoryboard {
    convenience init(name: String, bundle storyboardBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
        self.init(name: name, bundle: storyboardBundleOrNil)
    }

    convenience override init() {
        self.init(name: "SomeName", bundle: nil);
    }
}
```

Is this just a bug in Swift, or am I missing something vital?

UPDATE

This code creates an infinite loop when it is run, as I should have spotted earlier.

I'm thinking this is definitely a Swift bug and that I should be radaring it.

Comment: Interesting ... looks like in artefact in the bridging between an Obj-C factory method to a swift initialiser.

Comment: In fact, from the book "For consistency and simplicity, Objective-C factory methods get mapped as convenience initializers in Swift."

Comment: Problem is that it doesn't seem to be able to find that convenience initializer, given the "Extra argument 'name' in call" error. I tried just calling that initializer directly on my subclass, and it doesn't work, giving that same error. Change it straight UIStoryboard, and it does work.

Comment: Yes, look like 'automatic initialiser inheritance' is broken in this case I guess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is almost certainly a bug. [Filing it with Apple is probably a good idea](http://bugreport.apple.com).

Some ObjC APIs have a weird case of importing their factory methods to Swift only as "sort-of" initializers; you can see this is the case for `UIStoryboard` because the `init(...)` signature has a return type:

```
init(name: String, bundle storyboardBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) -> UIStoryboard
                                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You can't declare an `init` with a return type in your own Swift code — this is just an artifact of the ObjC-to-Swift importer. And when you have a class that imports like this, you get stuck in a situation where you can't write a subclass `init` that calls the designated initializer (because as far as Swift knows there is no designated initializer) and you can't call the factory method either. So, yeah, [sounds like a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com).

Note that even if this gets fixed you'll probably still need to override `init(name:bundle:)` before calling it from your own `convenience init()`. I'd expect the proper Swift API for this class to have a [failable initializer](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=17) (because you can specify a name or bundle that doesn't exist on disk). If you want to implement a non-failing `init()` in terms of a failable `init?(...)`, you have to delegate twice through an `init!(...)`, [as seen in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26516534/957768).